# Do these three sets of git commands do the same?

Tags: git, git-rebase, git-checkout, git-fetch

Do the following three sequences of command do the same:

Commands 1:

```
git fetch origin master
git rebase origin master
```

Commands 2:

```
git pull origin master --rebase
```

Commands 3:

```
git fetch origin master
git checkout FETCH_HEAD
```

My understanding is that all three commands do the same, which is:

1. "Download" all the commit from the specified branch of the specified remote repository.
2. Put the commit from the current branch "on top" of the downloaded commits.

Comment: `git checkout FETCH_HEAD` will just checkout `FETCH_HEAD` as detached head. No new commits will be put on top of it.

Comment: The reason why I do not understand what "git checkout FETCH_HEAD" does is that I do not understand what it means "to checkout a FETCH_HEAD".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your first set of commands, the `rebase` probably isn't what you intended; `rebase` doesn't take a remote as an argument.

(**UPDATE**: That said, under some circumstances `git` will interpret a remote name like a ref, and it's possible it will even represent what you mean.  I wouldn't rely on it myself, but:  If there is a symbolic ref `refs/remotes/origin/HEAD` - which can be interpreted as the "default branch" of `origin` and normally would exist if you created the local by cloning the origin at a time when it had a valid `HEAD` reference - then `origin` will expand to whatever `refs/remotes/origin/HEAD` points to.)

I think you meant

```
git rebase origin/master master
```

There are shorthand ways to write that based on the upstream configuration and already having `master` checked out, but whatever.  I'll go on assuming this is what you meant to do.

In that case your second command is more or less a shorthand for your first set of commands.

The third command, however, is not equivalent.  Whereas `rebase` creates new commits and moves refs (appearing to "move" an existing set of commits), `checkout` does neither of those things.  `checkout` merely moves the current `HEAD`.

To illustrate, let's suppose you have

```
A -- B <--(master)
              ^HEAD
```

and origin has

```
A -- C <--(master)
```

So if you `fetch` you'll get

```
A -- B <--(master)
 \            ^(HEAD)
  C <--(origin/master)
```

Now if you do a `rebase` as

```
git rebase origin/master master
```

(or just

```
git rebase
```

in a typical configuraiton) you'll end up with

```
  B
 /
A -- C <--(origin/master)
      \
       B' <--(master)
                 ^HEAD
```

I kept `B` in the diagram to illustrate why the commit at `master` is marked `B'`.  The original `B` commit does still exist (for now), and `B'` is a new and separate commit created in the `rebase`.  Because `B` is "dangling" it could eventually be garbage-collected.

That's also what you could expect if, instead of `fetch`, you had started with

```
git pull --rebase origin master
```

On the other hand, if you *don't* do a `rebase` and instead, after a `fetch`, say

```
git checkout FETCH_HEAD
```

you'd get

```
A -- B <--(master)
 \
  C <--(origin/master)
  ^(HEAD)
```

No new commit, no moved ref; just `HEAD` changes (and you're in detached `HEAD` state).

Comment: Do you mean by "more or less" that they are not exactly the same (or not always the same)?

Comment: I am not sure I understand this statement: "creates new commits and moves refs (appearing to "move" an existing set of commits)". Do you mean  by that exactly what I mean: it copies commits from remote repository and put the local commits on top of them?

Comment: @Roman - By "more or less" I mean that there are configuration options and other factors that might allow for special circumstances where the two don't behave the same; but in day-to-day use, you could use a `pull --rebase` interchangeably with a `fetch` followed by a `rebase`.

Comment: @Roman: By "creates new commits and moves refs": No, I do not mean copying commits from the remote. Like almost all git commands, `rebase` operates locally. The `pull` or `fetch` commands are the only ones involved in this discussion that interact with the remote. `rebase` works by creating new commits that make the same changes on a new base that old commits made on an old base; that is fundamentally what `rebase` is, so I suggest you start by reading the documentation on `rebase` first, then once you understand about that you can worry about what commands are equivalent.